# Stateful Component with Typescript and react-redux: Argument of type 'typeof MyClass' is not assignable to parameter of type Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I am trying to get into Typescript combined with React and Redux.

But I am struggling at the moment.

I got this error:

> ./src/containers/Hello.tsx
>   [tsl] ERROR in /home/marc/Development/TypeScript-React-Starter-master/src/containers/Hello.tsx(20,61)
>         TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof Hello' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<{ enthusiasmLevel: number; name: string; } & { onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusiasm; onDecrement: () => DecrementEnthusiasm; }>'.
>     Type 'typeof Hello' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<{ enthusiasmLevel: number; name: string; } & { onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusiasm; onDecrement: () => DecrementEnthusiasm; }>'.
>       Type 'Hello' is not assignable to type 'Component<{ enthusiasmLevel: number; name: string; } & { onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusiasm; onDecrement: () => DecrementEnthusiasm; }, ComponentState>'.
>         Types of property 'setState' are incompatible.
>           Type '{ (f: (prevState: {}, props: Props) => Pick<{}, K>, callback?: (() => any) | undefined): void; (state: Pick<{}, K>, callback?: (() => any) | undefined): void; }' is not assignable to type '{ (f: (prevState: ComponentState, props: { enthusiasmLevel: number; name: string; } & { onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusiasm; onDecrement: () => DecrementEnthusiasm; }) => Pick, callback?: (() => any) | undefined): void; (state: Pick<...>, callback?: (() => any)...'.
>             Types of parameters 'f' and 'f' are incompatible.
>               Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
>                 Type 'Props' is not assignable to type '{ enthusiasmLevel: number; name: string; } & { onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusiasm; onDecrement: () => DecrementEnthusiasm; }'.
>                   Type 'Props' is not assignable to type '{ onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusiasm; onDecrement: () => DecrementEnthusiasm; }'.
>                     Types of property 'onIncrement' are incompatible.
>                       Type '(() => void) | undefined' is not assignable to type '() => IncrementEnthusiasm'.
>                         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '() => IncrementEnthusiasm'.

That's my React Component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './Hello.css';

export interface Props {
  name: string;
  enthusiasmLevel: number;
  onIncrement?: () => void;
  onDecrement?: () => void;
}

class Hello extends React.Component<Props, {}> {

   render(){
     const { enthusiasmLevel, onIncrement, onDecrement } = this.props;

     if (enthusiasmLevel <= 0) {
       throw new Error('You could be a little more enthusiastic. :D');
     }

     return (
       <div className="hello">
         <div className="greeting">
           Hello {name + getExclamationMarks(enthusiasmLevel)}
         </div>
         <div>
           <button onClick={onDecrement}>-</button>
           <button onClick={onIncrement}>+</button>
         </div>
       </div>
     );
   }

}

export default Hello;

// helpers

function getExclamationMarks(numChars: number) {
  return Array(numChars + 1).join('!');
}
```

That's the file where the error happens:

```
import Hello from '../components/Hello';
import * as actions from '../actions/';
import { StoreState } from '../types/index';
import { connect, Dispatch } from 'react-redux';

export function mapStateToProps({ enthusiasmLevel, languageName }: StoreState) {
  return {
    enthusiasmLevel,
    name: languageName,
  };
}

export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch: Dispatch<actions.EnthusiasmAction>) {
  return {
    onIncrement: () => dispatch(actions.incrementEnthusiasm()),
    onDecrement: () => dispatch(actions.decrementEnthusiasm()),
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hello);
```

StoreState Interface:

```
export interface StoreState {
    languageName: string;
    enthusiasmLevel: number;
}
```

I am not sure whats wrong with that.
The only workaround, which worked was:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Hello as any);
```

which is an ugly solution in my eyes.

Comment: Can you post your StoreState interface ?

Comment: @Frank I added it.

Comment: I works for me. It looks like problem not in the component. (P.S. Also change Component<Props, {}> to Component<Props>)

Answer (score 0):

The type hints of your `Props` interface does not exactly match the interface expected by `connect()()`, as indicated in the error message:

> Type 'Hello' is not assignable to type 'Component<{ enthusiasmLevel: number; name: string; } & *{ onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusiasm; onDecrement: () => DecrementEnthusiasm; }*, ComponentState>'.

1. The `onIncrement` and `onDecrement` props must not be optional and
2. The `onIncrement` and `onDecrement` props do not return `void` but `IncrementEnthusiam` and `DecrementEnthusiam` respectively.

Your `Props` interface should look like this:

```js
export interface Props {
  name: string;
  enthusiasmLevel: number;
  onIncrement: () => IncrementEnthusiasm;
  onDecrement: () => DecrementEnthusiasm;
}
```